Assigning positive measure to open balls
Let $A$ be compact separable metric space, and let $\cup_{n\in \mathbb N} O_n$ be an open basis for its topology. Does there exist  a probability measure $\nu$ on $A$ such that $\nu(O_n)>0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

This is related to this question. But instead of just being Hausdoff, we impose additional assumptions that $A$ is separable and metrizable.

Pick a countable, dense subset of $A$ then asign a descrete probability distribution to this dense set so that all elements have positive probability
